# koma book chapter number with trailing .0?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script

By default, KOMA-Script scrbook produces chapters numbered like "1. Introduction". How can I get a chapter numbered like "1.0 Introduction"?

Comment: The answers below might be outdated, because KOMA-script changed since then. For another answer see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624207/4736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
% \def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.0} % or just put zero
% you need to redefine thesection, etc since their original definition depends on thechapter
\def\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}} 

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \section{A first section}
\end{document}
```

You can do this by redefine `\thechapter`, etc. Note that you need to redefine also `\thesection` etc otherwise they will be 1.1.1 or 1.0.1 depend on which `\def` above you use for `\thechapter`

Comment: Thanks! This almost works. First, it also requires numbers=noenddot, as in Herbert's solution. Second, it also needs something to adjust the space in the TOC entry between the chapter number and the chapter title, since some space gets eaten by that ".0". Any ideas?

Comment: @Jack Tanner Be honest I never used KOMA-Script (the english docs are never up to date and I don't read de, and it does not feel good to work with something without up to date docs). However when working with standard class I use `tocloft` for table of contents. And `memior` provide similar functionality. I guess you need to check `KOMA`'s manual to see if it provide a way to change the look of TOC or if pacakges like `tocloft` are compatible with `KOMA`

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sections will be numbered 1.0.x

Comment: did I said that it wouldn't? The OP didn't said anything about his section numbering ...