# Komascript scrbook \chaptermarkformat behavior

Tags: koma-script, scrbook

By default, `scrbook` prints `\chapter{Intro}` as

1 Intro

But I would like a `.0` appended to the numbering so that it prints. I was directed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/koma-book-chapter-number-with-trailing-0) which shows one way to achieve the desired effect.

But from reading the koma-script manual, I get the impression I should be using koma-script specific commands to fine tune the formatting and presentation of my document. That is why I scoured the manual and eventually found `\chaptermarkformat` which *seems* to be what I should use to change the formatting of the numbers in chapter headings.

So I tried

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter \autodot 0 \enskip}
```

but it had no effect, the formatting of the number in each chapter heading did not change from the default.

Any hints on why it does not change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you found is ten years old and outdated.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter.0
\autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Intro}
\label{cha:intro}

Some text.


\end{document}
```

See KOMA-script manual, text to `\chapterformat` in chapter 3, where I found the code I copied above and added a `.0`. It doesn't change the entry in the toc.

Comment: Thanks - Do you know why my solution did not work though? Is `\chaptermarkformat` not the format of the number that comes in the heading?

Comment: @Nukesub No idea, but you haven't provided your code except for one line. I just have remembered that I had seen a different definition of `\chapterformat` in the manual.

Comment: Any idea how to make the ToC entry consistent with this? I've tried playing around with `RedeclareSectionCommand` and `tocstyle` with no luck.

Comment: @Nukesub Please ask new question, I'm really occupied these days.